# PHP upload limit using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Evening,

Is there a way in which I can use .htaccess to specify a file upload limit for PHP? I've been getting some rather large files lately and I want to lower the upload limit to about 30MB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes There is:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 30MB
```

For more Info:

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php-directives-in-custom-htaccess-files/setting-the-php-maximum-upload-file-size-in-an-htaccess-file

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your htaccess file ;

php_value memory_limit 30M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M

Make sure php_value matches your php version for php 5 it would be php5_value

Thanks